Why is polyurethane with mixed-in stain not drying?
I sprayed polyurethane with a stain mixed in to use as a faux finish on maple wood. The first coat dried hard but the second coat is drying slowly and is easily scratched off. The temperature and humidity is very high and my be the problem. Any suggestions?

You can tell if temperature or humidity is the problem, and we cannot.  Measure them with a $10 thermometer/hygrometer or just look at local weather on your phone.  Read the instructions for both products and you'll know the answer.    The instructions will also give you clues about what else might be the problem if temp and humidity are not.  EG, if the two products are compatible or not.    This question is not answerable without a lot more information, and with that information you probably won't need to ask.
